# Vue Warning when passing data from blade template to vue

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I'm getting this error from vue

> [Vue warn]: Property or method "product" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property.

I'm not sure where I went wrong to get that error. Here is my code

Home.vue

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>This is the product page</h1>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: ['product'],

        data() {
          return {

          }
        },
        mounted() {
            console.log(this.product);
        }
    }
</script>
```

and this is my product.blade.php

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 mt-5">
        <div id="app">
            <home :product="product"></home>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and this is in my ProductsController

```
public function show(Product $product)
{
    return view('welcome', [
        'product' => $product
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<home :product="{{ $product }}"></home>
```

The **product** is coming from the your controller and to use it in blade, you have to use `{{ }}`

Comment: Thank you so much. I can't believe I missed something like that.